# Lambda read DynamoDB and send to ML Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

**Background:**

> I have a DynamoDB table with column's "TimeStamp | Data1 | Data2". I
>   also have a ML endpoint in SageMaker which needs Data1 and Data2 to
>   generate one output value(score).

**Question:**

> My ambition is to script a Lambda function (Java or Python) to read
>   the latest row in the DynamoDB table, and send this through the
>   Endpoint and receive the score.

**What I have tried:**

> I have only found guides where you do this by exporting the whole
>   DynamoDB table to s3 and in Data Pipeline send it to the Endpoint.
>   This is not how I want it to work!

Answer (score 3):

I am an engineer of Sagemaker team.

As I understand, you would like to use Lambda function to

1. Listen to DynamoDB table updates
2. Invoke Sagemaker endpoint for real-time predictions.

For (1), [DynamoDB stream](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/11/10/introducing-dynamodb-streams/) could be a wonderful place to start. Here is a [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.Tutorial.html) for processing DynamoDB streams using Lambda function:

For (2), here is an [step-by-step tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/call-an-amazon-sagemaker-model-endpoint-using-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/) for invoke Sagemaker endpoint for predictions inside Lambda function.

Hope this helps.